# Postman Client Credentials Flow with Azure AD protected ressource

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am currently using this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api

To check the Client Credentials Flow with OAuth in Azure AD. Theoretically the example works OK. Client App successfully communicates with the server App, obtaining first the OAuth Token from Azure AD token url. No problems there. However, I am trying to use Postman to check the Client Credentials Flow and I cannot get it to work.

In Postman, I should provide an **Access Token Url**, a **Client ID** and a **Client Secret**, **Grant Type** is set to **Client Credentials**. Using the same parameters as in the example provided by Microsoft's sample in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon, I get a **401** response when trying to access the web service. I think the main reason is because in Postman, I can not type the **resource** I want to access, so the received token is not "linked" to any resource and that is why the authorization fails in the web server? Could this be the reason? If that is the reason, then what should I do in the server, because, somehow it seems as if Postman's requirements should be the ones valid in the Client Credentials Flow (I mean, no **resource** should be given, according to the OAuth2 Client Credentials Flow, right?

This is the code for the Starup class in the sample downloaded from Microsoft's example

```
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
            });
    }
```

**ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]** is my Azure AD tentant, while 
**ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]** is the protected resource I need to access. Both values are required, if I do not provide the Audience, I get an error in .NET web API initialization.

Comment: There is a GitHub issue that tracks this: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I think the problem is that Azure Token server doesn't accept client credentials sent as an Authorization header. e.g.

```
Authorization: Basic YmE1NTZlYmItZGY2OS00NjBhLWEwMjItNTI0NWQ0MzA2N2UxOmVxVzlqaXRobXF2cVFiVWY5dmxaWnhZN2wwUzZhQ0pHSkExSGt0eUd3N0W6
```

but that's how Postman's "Get new access token" tool sends it. So it's isn't going to work.

If you look at [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) and search for "get a token" you will see it implies that client credentials should be supplied in the body.

```
POST /common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX&grant_type=client_credentials
```

This works fine but seems to contradict the [Oauth 2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1) which says:

> The authorization server MUST support the HTTP Basic    authentication
> scheme for authenticating clients that were issued a    client
> password.

**END EDIT**

You definitely *can* get a bearer token back without supplying a resource.

Notice that `resource` isn't even spelt correctly in the postman http body of the previous answer - it's spelt as `resrource` which is why it's value of `https://graph.microsoft.com` is ignored and does not match the `resource` sent back in the response `(00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000)`. Although funny enough they both relate to the api graph...but that's a digression.

Confusingly there are two ways of supplying client credentials to an Oauth 2.0 server and some servers don't accept both ways!

- 1 is adding a `basic auth` header which is set to Base64(ClientId +
  ":" + ClientSecret)
- 2 is adding clientId and clientSecret in the body of the request.

I guess that's the problem with Oauth 2.0 being a spec rather than a protocol...
See - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1

Postman's Request Token UI (see image below) uses method 1, but Azure auth server expects method 2. I know because I ran fiddler, and could see the request postman put together.

If you manually put the client credentials in the body e.g.

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=&client_id=ba556ebb-xxxx9-460a-ax2x-5245d43067e1&client_secret=eqW9jighghghgvlZZxY7l0S6aCJGJA1HktyGw7E=

and don't use a `Basic Auth` http header. You can get a bearer token back even *without* suppyling a resource.

This works fine - but obviously that's no good for you in terms of using postman to get and store your tokens!

[image]

Comment: I have not yet double checked the content in this post, but it is the first reasonable explanation as to why Postman still cannot get OAuth2 tokens from Azure using it's "Get New Access Token" dialog system which is designed to do exactly that.  If this is correct, it should be addressable somehow in postman, and hopefully there's a ticket. I've been searching for an answer for half a day and did not find one.

Comment: It seems to still be the case here in 2023. Correct me if I am wrong, but I have tried with Get New Access Token and it doesn't work. The method in the below screenshot with POST method and grant_type, client_id, client_secret and resource works for me.

Answer (score 4):

> I think the main reason is because in Postman, I can not type the resource I want to access, so the received token is not "linked" to any resource and that is why the authorization fails in the web server? Could this be the reason?

You are correct. To get the access token via **client credential flow**, we need to provide the **resource** in the request.

What did you mean that not able to type the resource? The resource parameter is a parameter we can contain it in the body and here is a figure for your reference:

[image]

And be ensure that the value of resrouce is eaque to the **audience** config used to protect the resource.

Comment: Yes, sure, if you were making a direct request to the OAuth2 token URL. The problem is I am not making the request to the Token URL, I am making a request to a REST service protected by Azure AD supporting Client Credentials Flow. In this case, it is Postman the one making the request to the Token URL, because I am using Postman's built in Authorization capabilities (the Authorization Tab at the far left of your image), using OAuth2 to request the token which fails because in Postman's Auth dialog, I see no way of typing the protected resource.

Comment: According to a response I received in Postman's Slack account:

In the client_credentials flow, the client_id & client_secret are sent in the Authorization header as specified in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4

That means that according to OAuth Specifications, the client_id and client_secret travels in the Authorization header, as opposed to the image you provided (which was also my understanding, since your example works correctly, as so does the test I created in C#, but they send these parameters in the form Body, not in Auth header). I am a little bit lost right now.

Comment: It is a little different when Azure AD implement the OAuth 2.0, we provide the require parameter in the body as figure above. And the client credential is same no Mather you send the request to the token endpoint directly or from an web API which protected by Azure AD. But in your scenario, we also need provide the token to pass the authorization to access the web API which protected. Then in the web api, we can construct the **Client Credential** flow same as in the Postman. More detail about this flow please refer [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only).

Comment: And we always need to specify the **resource** parameter in the body.

Comment: @Fei Xue I have also just tried to deploy the scaffolded WeatherForecast Web API .NET 7 project from VS 2022 to a Web App in Azure, enabled Easy Auth on the Web App in Azure and tested using Postman. I have made it work with v1 of the Azure Oauth2 token endpoint where I provide the grant_type, client_id, client_secret and resource. Than I get a Bearer Token that I then use in calling the WeatherForecast Web API and I get a HTTP 200 back with the weather data in JSON. I still don't understand the difference in Postman when using Authorization tab and Client Credentials and Get New Access Token.